# React native graph using event drops

Tags: react-native, d3.js, react-native-svg, event-drops

I working with Event drops in react js. This is working fine in web app. But I am trying to implement same into React-native mobile app. Unfortunately no success yet.

**Any help would be appreciated?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use this [Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pie-chart), It is working fine for me I implemented charts to my react native app through this library couples days back.

if it doesn't help check [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to implement something like this: https://marmelab.com/EventDrops/

Comment: That is fine, but I want to implement this using event-drops library. https://openbase.io/js/event-drops. This is not a static graph.

Comment: I have installed event-drops with all dependencies. But the problem is with selection library like d3.selection in react native

Comment: in react-native, there are no event drops, Still, event drops are only available for Web-based Applications and websites.

Comment: I know there are no event drops. Instead tap or double tab will work?

Comment: Yes so use graph instead of this.